# Start edit program from MacOS Photo's

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

While I am browsing trough my photo's in MacOS Photo's, I want to edit some files in Adobe Photoshop / Illustrator.
But I cant seem to find the option to "quicklauch" PS with the selected picture.

I did seem to find some outdated info about this (OSX) but that did not help me.

At the Photo's setting menu I only see 2 tabs:
"General" and "iCloud", there are no options for me to edit the default editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality was an iPhoto feature, never migrated to Photos.

Answer (score 0):

First, open Photoshop, Illustrator, or whatever app you want. Second, in the Photos app, select the pictures you want to edit. Third, drag those icons to the dock icon for Photoshop, Illustrator, or whatever app you are using. Photoshop, Illustrator, etc. should then open the selected images.

Comment: It does not work here
Photoshop version:2017.0.1
MacOS 10.12.3
If i drag it to the icon, it does nothing. But also when I hold the image above the icon and then drag it into PS it doesn't show or open the image

Comment: What version of OS X are you on? I can confirm it works with OS X El Capitan and the latest version of photoshop.

Comment: Damn you're quick, hadn't finished editing my comment :P
But your method does work from within finder or dragging it from my desktop.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to say then. I haven't tested for sure, but possibly you could select the photo in the Photos app and use Apple's share button. It looks like a square with an upwards arrow. Maybe there is a way to open the photo(s) in photoshop through the sharing menu.

Comment: Yea that is exactly what I am asking :D